# In crystal reports how to I make a default value appear on a null?

Tags: crystal-reports, null, formula

I'm using VS 2010 but I'm not sure on the Crystal reports what year it is. 2008 or 2010?  I want to display 'N/A' when a date field is null.  here is my formula

```
  If isnull({usp_print_get;1.Cit_Date}) then 'its null' else 'not null'
```

It will print 'not null' when there is a date but if there isn't a date it just leaves the space blank instead of printing 'its null'  I've checked the database and the date field for that record is indeed null and not a space or empty string.  Any help is appreciated. Eventually I'd like to print either 'N/A' when its null or the actual Cit_Date. Right now I'm just using the strings to test.

Comment: Are you using a SQL command or table?

Comment: usp_print_get is a stored procedure that gets information to print from sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your formula, it should work, it's just the syntax that is odd.  Use double quotes instead of single.

```
IF isnull({usp_print_get;1.Cit_Date}) THEN 
  "N/A"
ELSE
  " "
```

But if you want to want to use the date with this formula you will have to convert it to a string. The output has to be the same data type, it messes up the Formatting option.

```
IF isnull({usp_print_get;1.Cit_Date}) THEN 
  "N/A"
ELSE
  TO_TEXT({usp_print_get;1.Cit_Date}, "MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Format the date however way you want.

If you are debugging, put it formula and the date column side by side in your report.
It's easier to check if it's working.

Comment: The date is actually coming in as a string not a date type, sorry I didn't say that. I have the formula in the Display String formula for the field, should it go there?

Comment: I tried putting the formula on a null column within a display string and it didn't work.  Nulls can really mess up your report so I would recommend you stick it in a formula.

Comment: The display string formula is really intended for column formatting. It's not surprising that Crystal doesn't even evaluate it for null columns. @ca_wan has the right idea: this logic needs to go into its own formula.